# Is it possible to include modules in other modules in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, module

Is it possible to include modules in other modules in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

That said, the whole double-inclusion thing can be bad. There's a [gem for that](https://github.com/adrianomitre/retroactive_module_inclusion).

Answer (score 3):

Sure, but...

Before you do that, ask yourself what distinction caused you to split the code across two modules, and then ask why that distinction wouldn't be meaningful to your consumers.